# Remove whitespace from fgets char array

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program calculating an average of integers in a given string that adds them until it encounters `-1`, sample input being `1 2 3 4 5 -1`.

How do I remove spaces from array so that my sum calculation works?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "source.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LEN 1000

void calculate_average() {
    int test, size, sum, i, j, k, temp;
    int grade;
    char input[MAX_LEN];
    char formattedInput[MAX_LEN];
    double avg;
    size = 0;
    avg = 0.0;
    test = 1;
    k = 0;
    sum = 0;

    fgets(input, 10, stdin);
    for (j = 0; j < strlen(input); ++j) {
        if (input[j] = ' ') {
            ;
        } else {
            temp = input[j];
            formattedInput[k] = temp;
            ++k;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; atoi(input[i]) != -1; ++i) {
        if (atoi(formattedInput[i]) == -1) {
            test = -1;
            avg = sum / size;
        } else {
            ++size;
            sum = sum + atoi(formattedInput[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("%f\n", avg);
}
```

Comment: @xing You made me realize that it is to restrictive, I have changed it to MAX_LEN.
Correct output should be 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will recommend using `strtod` so that you can process your input string without the need for preprocess,
As a side note in your original code `sum / size` will cast to `int` and you will lose precision, so you need a cast first
I change your function as follow

```
#define MAX_LEN 1000

void calculate_average(){
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char input[MAX_LEN];

    fgets(input, 10, stdin);

    char *start, *end;
    start = input;
    while(1){
        int temp = strtod(start, &end);
        if(temp == -1)
           break;
        if(*end == 0)
            break;
        start = end;
        sum += temp;
        count++;
    }

    double avg = (double)sum / count;
    printf("%f\n", avg);
}
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, thank you. I am just beginning to learn C, how does the strtod extract integers from the string? I can see those *start and *end chars are pointers, why are they needed?

Comment: @RafiRosa, Im glad it helped, You may want to accept the answer, please consider reading [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtod.htm) link for more info on `strtod`, starting from start it moves until it detects illegal character and converts the string to int up to that point, then returning its address in `end` pointer so you can keep going from that point on,

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sscanf` along with `%n` format specifier to read in the space separated numbers.

Example:

```
int temp = 0;
int bytesread = 0;
char *ptr = input;
while (sscanf(ptr, "%d%n", &temp, &bytesread) > 0 && temp != -1) {
   ptr += bytesread;
   sum = sum + temp;
}
```

Where `%n` will return number of bytes read from the string, thus use this value to advance the `ptr` to point to next number.